# print formatting in java (Array/For Loops)

Tags: java

This is my first program in java. For the life of me no matter what I do. It won't won't won't work. :(

Here is my method that I am outputting information in.

```
private static int showAll(int[] order, String[] name, int last) 
{
int end = order.length;


System.out.println("     " + "The Godfather's Pizza" + "     " + "\n" 
+ "**********************************" 
+ "\n     Order Number" + "    Customer\n     -----------     ---------\n");


    for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) 


        {

        System.out.printf("%6d %6d%s" + order[i] + name[i]);


            end = end + 1;
        }      

System.out.println("\n          End of Report");



return end;
}
```

Here is an example of my output:

```
    The Godfather's Pizza     
**********************************
 Order Number    Customer
 -----------     ---------

  0              null
  0              null
  0              null
  0              null
  0              null

      End of Report
```

My question is... how do I format my outputs? I know how to in other programming languages and didn't think it would be such a pain?

```
System.out.printf("%6d %6d%s" + order[i] + name[i]);
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: format your outputs to go what?

Comment: `System.out.printf("%6d %6d%s", order[i], name[i]);` ....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just want to print an Integer and a String and format it with out using "    " a bunch of spaces? I thought that was pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
System.out.printf("%6d %6d%s" + order[i] + name[i]);
```

to something more like...

```
System.out.printf("%6d %15s", order[i], name[i]);
```

Remember `printf` takes parameters, which define the values which are substituted for your format

You might also want to take a look at [Formatting Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more details

```
public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] order = new int[10];
        String[] name = new String[10];
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            order[index] = index;
            name[index] = Character.toString((char)(65 + index));
        }
        showAll(order, name, 1);
    }

    private static int showAll(int[] order, String[] name, int last) {
        int end = order.length;

        System.out.println("     " + "The Godfather's Pizza" + "     " + "\n"
                        + "**********************************"
                        + "\n     Order Number" + "    Customer\n     -----------     ---------\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {

            System.out.printf("%6d %15s\n", order[i], name[i]);

            end = end + 1;
        }

        System.out.println("\n          End of Report");

        return end;
    }
}
```

Remember, you can't format `null` values, you need to either provide proper values or test for the `null` condition, something like

```
System.out.printf("%6d %15s\n", order[i], (name[i] == null ? "" : name[i]));
```

...for example

Comment: Error = Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s

Comment: You can't format `null` values, you could use `(name[i] == null ? "" : name[i])` to overcome it, or pass actually, no-null values...

Comment: @Whitney Probably, with that last error, you left one `%` sign too many in your format string, or you didn't change both the `+` signs for commas.  What happens here is that every `%` sign is the start of a little sequence that gets replaced by one of the arguments after the initial string.  So if you've got three `%` signs, you need three arguments IN ADDITION TO the format string.